# Open Source 2D Game Engine that supports Hexagon Maps for .NET

Tags: .net, game-engine

I cannot find a 2D game engine to create hexagon maps for .net. The best I can find is Xconq (http://sourceforge.net/projects/xconq/) and pygame. Does anybody where I can find any? preferrably one like xconq.

Thank you for your time and effort. I really apprecate it.

**Edit:** I would like to have feature of a strategic nature. Like adding custom AIs, path finding, etc. Xcong is an engine for turn-based strategy games.

Comment: I've thought about trying to rewrite XConq to .NET

Comment: I have thought the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

Does this help? *Hexagonal grid for games and other projects - Part 1* at http://www.codeproject.com/KB/graphics/hexagonal_part1.aspx

Comment: It is lacking in game-engine features.

Answer (score 0):

You should check out [Mappy](http://tilemap.co.uk/mappy.php). I remember using it a while ago and it was pretty good. They have an [XNA Playback library](http://xnalibrarymappymaps.codeplex.com/) as well, so you can look at the .NET code for reading Mappy files

Comment: I don't need a map editor. I need a game-engine that provides a framework for AI handling, generating a hex tile map, path finding, drawing sprites, and stuff like that. Through the site I did find a link to http://boogame.sourceforge.net/ which I am going to check out.

Comment: BooGame does not have any strategic game features. :(

Comment: You might want to clarify your question. A 2D tile-engine is not the same as a game-engine. I don't know of any engines that will provide you with AI and hex maps without some coding on your part. Could look into TorqueX but I'm not sure how well that handles hex maps out the box.