# Any code samples open-source-engines, or open source hex tile games, references for writing Hex Tile based Games?

Tags: game-engine, hexagonal-tiles

Using other questions on here I found Amit's Page on Games including a section on [Hex Tiles](http://www-cs-students.stanford.edu/~amitp/gameprog.html#hex) which also links to a game coding wiki [here](http://sc.tri-bit.com/Hex_Grids).

I am looking for suggestions:

(a) libraries, engines or code samples in any language. I have found one in python, [PGU+pygame](http://www.pygame.org/project/108/), but looking for more.

(b) open source hex-tile tactics or strategy games.

Because google can find things for me, what I'm hoping is that you have actually used one. So if you googled and then posted, then this is nothing better than let-me-google-that-for you.  Much appreciated if (i) you have used it, (ii) seriously, any language at all is okay, C/C++, python, java, flash/flex, whatever.

[Related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1838656/how-do-i-represent-a-hextile-hex-grid-in-memory) and another [related question but .net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2443140/open-source-2d-game-engine-that-supports-hexagon-maps-for-net)

Comment: seems pretty broad. - are you fluent in game theory mathematics?  how about linear algebra?

Comment: I've voted to close and flagged for deletion on  this question because it's no longer an on-topic question at stackoverflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used PGU a number of years ago to make a hex based game for PyWeek, you can take a look at the code if you want to. :)

http://www.pyweek.org/e/PySwec/

I've got a more updated version at home which is quite a bit better but unless you actually want to play the game you should be fine with that. :)

Answer (score 3):

[Battle For Wesnoth](http://www.wesnoth.org/) is a complete, open-source, turn-based strategy hex-based game.  Its written in C++.  Quite a good game too.

I'm sure there would be something valuable in there, although I've only have a brief browse of the source myself.

Answer (score 1):

Based on another question here on stackoverflow, there is XConq, an open source turn based tile game.